# Php переменные. Кавычки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста какой из вариантов быстрее и правильнее будет.

1. ```
   $query = $bd->query("SELECT idusers FROM postlike WHERE id_users=".$myrow2['id']."");
   ```
2. ```
   $query = $bd->query("SELECT idusers FROM postlike WHERE id_users=$myrow2[id]");
   ```
3. ```
   $query = $bd->query("SELECT idusers FROM postlike WHERE id_users='$myrow2[id]'");
   ```

Comment: > какой из вариантов быстрее

[Преждевременная оптимизация](https://www.google.ru/search?q=преждевременная+оптимизация) и экономия на спичках

> правильнее

Если `id_users` - поле числового типа, то первый или второй, а третий неправильный, если строкового - то наоборот. Хотя на самом деле все три варианта открывают безграничный простор для инъекций.

Comment: Правильнее будет использовать [PDO][1]!


  [1]: http://ru2.php.net/pdo_mysql